# Parsing JSON response body in Express.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

A Node.js/Express.js app makes a RESTful call to another app and receives JSON in response.  But the JSON response is not being parsed into new variables.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below, so that the JSON body can be successfully parsed into new variables that the receiving Node.js/Express.js app can use for further processing?**

Here  is the Node.js/Express.js code which is currently receiving the `JSON` `body` `response`:

```
var url = require('url');
var request = require('request');

app.get('/user**', function(req, res) {
    console.log("You Hit The User Route TOP");
    request.get(authServer + '/uaa/user', function (error, response, body) {
        if(error){console.log('ERROR with user request.')}
        if (!error){// && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(response.statusCode); console.log(body);

             response.on('data', function(chunk){
                 console.log('inside response.on(data...)');
                 body += chunk;
             });

             response.on('end', function(){
                 console.log('inside response.on(end...)');
                 body = JSON.parse(body);
                 var text = '';
                 for (var key in body){
                      text += 'Index is: ' + key + 
                              '\nDescription is:  ' + body[key] 
                 }

                 // The Description is:  "descriptive string"  
                 console.log("Got a response: ", text);
                 res.send(text);            
             });
            res.send(body);
        };
    }).auth(null, null, true, bearerToken);//this inserts bearer token in the GET request
    console.log("You Hit The User Route BOTTOM");
});
```

Here are the `nodemon` logs for the `GET` shown in the code.  **Note that the `response.on()` blocks are never called because their SYSO never prints**:

```
You Hit The User Route TOP
You Hit The User Route BOTTOM
200
{ long JSON string, which is formatted and truncated below for easier reading }
GET /user 200 182.862 ms - 1296
```

And here is the formatted and truncated `JSON` `body`, which illustrates the format of the data that needs to be parsed into Node.js/Express.js JavaScript variables:

```
{
    "details":  
        {
            "remoteAddress":"127.0.0.1",
            "sessionId":null,
            "tokenValue":"SomeLongTokenString",
            "tokenType":"Bearer",
            "decodedDetails":null
        },
    "authenticated":true,
    "userAuthentication":
        {
            "details":null,
            "authorities":
                [
                    {
                        "authority":"ROLE_ADMIN"
                    },
                    {
                        "authority":"ROLE_USER"
                    }
                ],
            "authenticated":true,
            "principal":"user",
            "credentials":"N/A",
            "name":"user"
        },
    "name":"user"
}
```

Comment: You're immediately printing out the `body` variable before you've done `JSON.parse` on it. Why would it be parsed at that point?

Comment: I meant on this line (`console.log(response.statusCode); console.log(body);`). You need to wait until it's been processed in the `end` event as peteb said. Either that or remove the `end` event entirely. Upon closer inspection, I don't even know why you have that there. You're acting as though `body` is being generated by a stream but it shouldn't be.

Comment: Like I said, get rid of those. They're pointless. Remove the `response.on` blocks and try just doing `body = JSON.parse(body); console.log(typeof body);`

Comment: If it's saying `object` that *means it has been parsed.* JSON is a string which is parsed into an object. Then you can access your values by doing `body.name`, `body.authorities`, etc. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/39qde8k1/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you're acting as though `response` is a stream that's incrementally giving you the JSON but you've already proven to yourself that's not true with your first `console.log(body)` statement. Instead, you can parse `body` immediately and begin working on it. You can also simplify your request handler.

```
if (error) {
  console.log('ERROR with user request.')
  return res.sendStatus(500);
}

body = JSON.parse(body);
var text = '';
for (var key in body) {
  text += 'Index is: ' + key + '\nDescription is:  ' + body[key]
}
// The Description is:  "descriptive string"  
console.log("Got a response: ", text);
res.send(text);
```

Comment: Per your comment above, the code that actually worked is as follows: `console.log('body.principal is: ');console.log(body.principal);
        console.log('body.authenticated is: ');console.log(body.authenticated);
        console.log('body.clientOnly is: ');console.log(body.clientOnly);
        console.log('body.name is: ');console.log(body.name);`

Comment: @DollarCoffee I have. No offense but I would appreciate it if you wouldn't talk to me as though I'm a new user. It's always a good idea to clean up comments. I would even argue that you should have left some of your comments up so future users could see how we came to the correct conclusion.

Comment: @MikeC He definitely should've now, your comments make essentially no sense since half of the conversation is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The following line doesn't wait for your response to be parsed.

`res.send(body);`

Remove it and wait to respond from your `response.on('end')` event.

---

#### Edit to include restructured request

I'd structure your request differently. You're not streaming your response so there shouldn't be much reason to listen for response events. Also you can get rid of your need for `JSON.parse()` by letting request handle that for you by indicating that the returning body is JSON.

```
request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: authServer + '/uaa/user', 
    json: true, // indicates the returning data is JSON, no need for JSON.parse()
    auth: {
        user: null,
        password: null,
        sendImmediately: true,
        bearer: bearerToken 
    }
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if(error){
      console.log('ERROR with user request.');
      return res.sendStatus(500);  // Return back that an error occurred
    }
    else {
        console.log(response.statusCode); 
        console.log(body);

        var text = '';
        for (var key in body) {
            text += 'Index is: ' + key + '\nDescription is:  ' + body[key];
        }

        return res.status(200).send(text);       
     }  
});
```